# NextJS - ReferenceError: Request is not defined | Reading old version of Node [solved]

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm, next.js, nvm

When I run npm run dev in my nextjs project I get the following error:

```
.../node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request.js:28
class NextRequest extends Request {
                          ^

ReferenceError: Request is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request.js:28:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at Module.mod.require (.../node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/adapters/next-request.js:37:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)

Node.js v17.4.0
```

When I run node -v I get:

```
v20.9.0
```

I have already uninstalled node from my machine and reinstalled it using nvm.

From what I understood nextjs and the packages I have installed are complaining because I am not using the required node version. However since in my terminal when I run node -v I get that I am using v20.9 I'm not sure why else Nextjs isn't detecting the correct node version

Anyone know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 26):

Open terminal inside your project and then run below mentioned command

`npm i node@lts`

Comment: This does not work on a pc using v 16.15.1  I observed that it works for all versions of node greater that 18.

Comment: I says No matching version found for

Answer (score 9):

I got this issue when using a node version below 18 which is actually required by nextJs 13. If you are not using node version manager, I suggest you install it you can find details about how to install it [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md)

Then run `nvm install 18` this will install and set your current version to 18. Then just run `yarn dev` or `npm run dev` to start your development server.

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest node LTS version

For windows download latest LTS version from https://nodejs.org/en
For linux or mac use nvm https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by uninstalling node and npm completely from my machine using the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x).

I then installed node and npm again using their official [website](https://nodejs.org/en/download).

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest version or changing node version by NVM will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Please try upgrading your node to 18.17.0 or higher
[image: package.json on next package]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).